# How to use data (rather than an identifier) to grant postgres permissions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-grant, postgresql-9.6

I want to use the following function (as a trigger on a table's inserts):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_authid_fn() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  GRANT ALL ON DATABASE testdb TO NEW.username;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 3:   GRANT ALL ON DATABASE testdb TO NEW.username;
```

because `New.username` is value, rather than an identifier.

How can I achieve this `GRANT`?

Comment: just dynamically?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Could you elaborate?  How do I do this dynamically inside a function?

Comment: sure. answered with working code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntactically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_authid_fn() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  execute format ('GRANT ALL ON DATABASE testdb TO %I',NEW.username);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I doubt it is a good idea in general